# Не могу проверить по значению?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет ,хотел проверить наличие интернета вот таким способом ...Но ни как не могу проверить метод `onPostExecute` у него вечно условие `false`

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer yoxlama) {
        super.onPostExecute(yoxlama);
        if (yoxlama == 1) {
        System.out.println("vse ok polucil svoy sttaus ");

         }
    }

    public int isCheck(){
        try {

        return 0;
    }
```

Я ведь отслеживю и там код 200 все ок ,но почему то возвращается  `return 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con.getResponseCode()!=200
```

Если равно 200, у Вас возвращается 0.

Вы имели в виду

```
con.getResponseCode() == 200
```

Comment: axaxaxaxaxa да да ))))))я запутался от усталости это спасибо))))))))))))0